# BULK INSERT not inserting properly from CSV

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I am trying to use `BULK INSERT` to add rows to an existing table from a .csv file. For now I have a small file for testing purposes with the following formatting:

```
UserID,Username,Firstname,Middlename,Lastname,City,Email,JobTitle,Company,Manager,StartDate,EndDate
273,abc,dd,dd,dd,dd,dd,dd,dd,dd,dd,dd
274,dfg,dd,dd,dd,dd,dd,dd,dd,dd,dd,dd
275,hij,dd,dd,dd,dd,dd,dd,dd,dd,dd,dd
```

And this is what my query currently looks like:

```
BULK INSERT DB_NAME.dbo.Users
    FROM 'C:\data.csv'
    WITH
    (
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
```

When I execute this query it returns 1 row affected. I checked the entry in the table and noticed that the data in the file is inserted in the table as a single row.

What could be causing this? What I am trying to accomplish is insert those rows in individual rows in the table. See (long)image below
[image]

The first column is actually an IDENTITY column so in the file I just specified a integer even though it will be overwritten by the auto generated ID as I am not sure how to tell the query to start inserting from the second field yet.

There are more columns created in the actual table than specified in the file as not everything needs to be filled. Could that be causing it?

Comment: Check in your favorite text editor to see what all symbols are. Eg in Notepad++ enable "Show All Symbols". Perhaps your rows are terminated with `\r` instead of `\r\n`.

Comment: For testing could you create a temp table without the identity field and take out the WITH statement to see what data you get returned?

Comment: Depending on characters encoding, new line characters are marked differently. Have you tried with `/r/n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are loading data into the first column. To skip a column create a view over your table with just the columns you want to load and BULK INSERT into view. See below example (from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179250.aspx):

```
CREATE VIEW v_myTestSkipCol AS  
    SELECT Col1,Col3  
    FROM myTestSkipCol;  
GO  

USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
BULK INSERT v_myTestSkipCol  
FROM 'C:\myTestSkipCol2.dat'  
WITH (FORMATFILE='C:\myTestSkipCol2.xml');  
GO
```

What I would recommend you do instead is to create a staging table which matches the file exactly. Load data into that and then use INSERT statement to copy it into your permanent table. This approach is much more robust and flexible. For example, after loading the staging table you can perform some data validation or cleanup before loading the permanent table.

Comment: Please [don't post identical answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question*. I've deleted [the other copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40757662/simple-sql-bulk-insert-not-working/40758128#40758128), since this one has been well received.